# Certificates/SSL via SSL-Proxy vs. real certificate for a server

Tags: ssl, ssl-certificate

While researching the different certificate types I've come across hosters that offer what they call [SSL-Proxy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SSL_termination_proxy) type installations for their servers. I'm concerned about this idea, as it defeats what I would consider major traits of the TLS infrastructure: Point-to-point encryption from the users browser to the receiving server.

1. Is there any way (besides considering all domain-validated certificate sites to be suspect) to tell a site employing an SSL proxy from a site where my data is actually encrypted to the receiving server?
2. Besides not having endpoint-to-endpoint encryption (in the above mentioned sense), are there any other problems of this type of infrastructure I'm not aware of?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SSL/TLS only **provides transit security** for your data and no guarantees what happens at other end of your connection.  If your worried about that you shouldn't send the data in the first place.

The trust chain provided by the SSL/TLS certificate gives a reasonable guarantee that the system you sending your data to actually belongs to (or is trusted by) the owner of the domain name, but tells you nothing about the system and application architecture that the owner has deployed.

Comment: That's a good argument/reasoning. Thanks.